# Is there a logical for-all in clojure.core.logic?

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to solve the first puzzle in Smullyan's To Mock a Mockingbird using clojure.core.logic, not because it is particularly hard, but rather as an exercise. The puzzle states that there's a garden with three colors of flowers: red, yellow, and blue. Each color is present at least once and no matter what three flowers you pick there will be a red and a yellow one among them. Question: is the third necessarily blue?
The basic skeleton of the logic code is quite straightforward:

```
(run 5 [flowers]
   (counto flowers 3)
   (containso flowers [:red :yellow])
   (fresh [garden]
          (containso garden [:red :yellow :blue])
          (containso garden flowers)
          (forall [flower-selection] (...))))
```

`counto` and `containso` are manually implemented and do the obvious thing. I'm new to this so there might be existing library support that I'm missing. The important line is the one beginning with `forall`. `forall` is basically what I wish would exist, but can't seem to find. The only construct I'm aware of that could go in this place is `fresh`. But `fresh` essentially performs existential quantification ∃. What I want here is universal quantification ∀.
I'm not interested in a garden for which it is *possible* to select three flowers which contain a red and a yellow one. I'm interested in a garden which *necessarily* leads to such a choice.

Comment: `all` ? maybe - found here https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/Examples - (probably not though)

Answer (score 2):

Even if there were a forall, this approach isn't really going to work, because the garden could be arbitrarily large, and to test all combinations of three flowers from an infinite garden will take an infinite amount of time.

And even if you did *that*, you would still not be done, because you've only proven that there exists one garden which satisfies this property: you haven't proven that *all* gardens which meet the initial conditions also satisfy the property.

core.logic is "just" a way of modeling search problems that makes it easy to prune subtrees of the search space that are uninteresting. If you are trying to prove a universal statement about an infinite search space, you will need to prune in some way that limits the maximum size of the search space. I don't see any obvious way of doing this in core.logic for this problem, short of thinking some more about the original problem, which will of course lead straight to the solution, without needing core.logic at all.

Comment: Have you read "To Mock a Mockingbird"? I'm curious if you would recommend this; also, if there are any similar books to this, I would love to hear any recommendations you might be willing to share.

Comment: Sure, any of Raymond Smullyan's books are good for understanding logical thinking, and TMaM in particular has a long section on the foundations of functional programming. I don't think I've ever *finished* one of his books: the puzzles just get too hard for me to do. I don't think they're particularly related to logic programming, though. Also, at http://doors.malloys.org I host a randomly-generated puzzle game (not written by me) based on the puzzles in "The Lady or the Tiger", which I invite you to try out.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info, and I will try out the puzzle you suggest!

Comment: It might be possible to implement Prolog's [`forall/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2) predicate in core.logic, but I haven't seen an implementation of it yet.